# error with npm install hubot-irc on windows 10 x64

Tags: npm, hubot, gyp

[npm install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKNfa.png)

I tried to install a hubot adapter [hubot-irc](https://github.com/nandub/hubot-irc) for my own bot, but got an error with `npm install`:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not fi
>   nd WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid versio
>   n number. [F:\Skitta\Documents\GitHub\mybot-irc\node_modules\hubot-irc\node_modules\irc\node_modules\iconv\build\libico
>   nv.vcxproj]
>   TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [F:\Skitta\Documents\Gi
>   tHub\mybot-irc\node_modules\hubot-irc\node_modules\irc\node_modules\iconv\build\libiconv.vcxproj]```
>
> gyp ERR! build error
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:2
>   69:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>   gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuil
>   d"
>   gyp ERR! cwd F:\Skitta\Documents\GitHub\mybot-irc\node_modules\hubot-irc\node_modules\irc\node_modules\iconv
>   gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
>   gyp ERR! not ok
>   npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing node-icu-charset-detector@0.0.7
>   npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing iconv@2.1.11

how to fix it?

Comment: Please include the error message as text in your post so it can be found by others facing the same issue.

Comment: `Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [F:\Skitta\Documents\Gi
tHub\mybot-irc\node_modules\hubot-irc\node_modules\irc\node_modules\iconv\build\libiconv.vcxproj]`

Answer (score 0):

node-gyp is the likely culprit as it's used to build native dependencies. It's not obvious but it probably needs to be configured. Follow the notes for [Windows install](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/README.md#installation) and take special note of your version of Windows and the all Windows versions section.